# bash named file descriptors redirections remain open with builtins : anomaly?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

`/bin/echo message {f}>/tmp/file`

and `echo message {f}>/tmp/file`

behave differently (using bash 4.2.46).

The first closes the file descriptor after running, as expected, while the second doesn't.

Demonstration:

if I run `/bin/echo` with a redirection to a named file descriptor like this :

`echo "before: f=${f-unset}"; /bin/echo message {f}>/tmp/file; echo "after: f=${f-unset}"; ls -l /proc/self/fd`

I get this, which I consider as normal output :

```
before: f=unset
message
after: f=unset
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:16 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:16 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:16 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:16 3 -> /proc/551733/fd
```

I consider it normal because when a redirection is specified on a line, it applies only to the command being run on this line.
The file descriptor is not meant to remain open afterwards.

And indeed, there is no reason why

`/bin/echo message {f}>/tmp/file`
would behave differently as, say :

`/bin/echo message 12>/tmp/file`

Now comes the strange thing :

If I run a builtin command like `echo` instead of `/bin/echo`

`echo "before: f=${f-unset}"; echo message {f}>/tmp/file; echo "after: f=${f-unset}"; ls -l /proc/self/fd`

I get this :

```
before: f=unset
message
after: f=10
total 0
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:27 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:27 1 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:27 10 -> /tmp/file
lrwx------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:27 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 user group 64 May  2 15:27 3 -> /proc/575192/fd
```

A file descriptor 10 was open and remains open in the shell afer running the echo command.

But I would think that there is no reason why, for instance

`echo message {f}>/tmp/file` would behave any differently than

`echo message 12>/tmp/file`

I'd expect none of them to leave the new file descriptor open afer running.

The only builtin that should keep redirections open is `exec`
( not even the `:` builtin ).

You could say "why would anyone do that if it's not to keep the file descriptor?", but it's a matter of consistency accross the whole bash shell.
If someone whishes to keep a new file descriptor, they should use `exec`, not `:`

Is it a bug, or is there something deeper that I am missing ?

If anyone can shed a light on this, thanks...

Comment: There's at least an aspect of orthogonality here. I think what happens is that the file gets opened, then when a fork occurs, the *parent* closes the file, leaving it open only in the child, where it gets closed/discarded when the child exits). No fork, no special handling of the file descriptor. It's also only the shell special built-ins that tend to have special handling. `echo` is not a special built-in.

Comment: @Regor: AFIK bash 4.2.46 does not have named file descriptors. Did you find it described in your man page?

Comment: @user1934428 That was added in 4.1-alpha